# Unity. Инициализация скрипта

Tags: unity3d

Вопрос простой. Первый скрипт создает объекты по префабу(шаблону). На шаблоне второй скрип с своими переменными. Как в первом скрипте при создании объекта передать нужные данные в скрипт этого объекта ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любые `MonoBehaviour` "скрипты" на обэктах это компонэнты. для получения ссылки используется:

`type MyScr = YourObject.`[GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)`<type>()`.

Юр, пиши по украински, твой ломанный-переломанный русский читать **не возможно**.

Comment: YourObject.GetComponent<type>() - і далі можна отримати доступ до полів або викликати методи ? Бачу Гугл не дуже мені допоміг з перекладом ну що ж ось так завжди іноді навіть не хочеться нічого писати чи питати бо потім стидно :( . Дякую за допомогу.

Comment: Ага, гугл наделал ошибок в словах... ну да...